# pre-commit not able to discover any golang files in nested go module

Tags: git, go, pre-commit-hook, pre-commit, pre-commit.com

I have a large repo in the likes of `github.com/myusername/myrepo`

Now within that repo (for reasons beyond the scope of this question) I have initialised the following `go` module: `github.com/myusername/myrepo/eck-user-mgmt`

Here is my `github.com/myusername/myrepo/eck-user-mgmt/.pre-commit-config.yaml`

```
---
files: ^eck-user-mgmt/
repos:
  - repo: git://github.com/dnephin/pre-commit-golang
    rev: v0.4.0
    hooks:
      - id: go-fmt
      - id: go-imports
      - id: go-unit-tests
      - id: go-mod-tidy
      - id: golangci-lint
```

However no `go` files/modules/whatever is discovered

```
▶ g add .pre-commit-config.yaml && pre-commit run
go fmt...............................................(no files to check)Skipped
go imports...........................................(no files to check)Skipped
go-unit-tests........................................(no files to check)Skipped
go-mod-tidy..........................................(no files to check)Skipped
golangci-lint........................................(no files to check)Skipped
```

This is run from where `pre-commit-config.yaml` resides, i.e. `~/work/myrepo/eck-user-mgmt`

why is that?

p.s. I know this is not the best practice in terms of `go` module management, I just want to know if there is a way with the make `pre-commit` work with `go` in the context of the specific setup

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can the python pre-commit tool consider a subdirectory as a base of the project?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64773189/can-the-python-pre-commit-tool-consider-a-subdirectory-as-a-base-of-the-project)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The go command generally runs in the context of a *main* module and its dependencies. It finds the main module by looking for a `go.mod` file in the current working directory and its parent directories.

If your pre-commit is run in the root directory of the repository and there's no `go.mod` file there, commands will be run outside any module. So `go mod tidy` and `go test ./...` won't do anything for example.

You'll likely need to run those commands within each module. You can locate directories containing `go.mod` files in a shell script:

```
modfiles=($(find . -type f -name go.mod))
for f in "${modfiles[@]}"; do
  pushd "$(dirname "$f")"
  ### presubmit commands
  popd
done
```

Comment: this isn't correct -- the reason OP is seeing the "no files to check" is due to their invocation of `pre-commit`

Answer (score 2):

Just adding up to the approach suggested by @Jay Conrod.

Since it seems `pre-commit` situations do not get along so well with monorepos and given that this becomes even more complex when it comes to `go`, I opted for the following `.git/pre-commit`

```
GOMODULESFILENAME="gomodules"

declare -a gomodarray

precommit() {
    go mod tidy
    go fmt
    go test ./... -coverprofile cover.out;
    go tool cover -func cover.out
    rm cover.out
}

while read -r line;
do  
    gomodarray+=("$(echo "$line")")
done<gomodules

for f in "${gomodarray[@]}"; do
        echo "Running golang pre-commit actions for project: $f"
        sleep 1
        pushd "$f"
        precommit
        popd
done
```

where `gomodules` is a file at the root of the repo listing line by line all go modules of the repo.

Answer (score 0):

`(no files to check)Skipped` means that nothing is matching the set of `types` / `files` / `exclude` for the specific hooks

looking at your setup you have:

- ** top level **: `files: ^eck-user-mgmt/`
- at each hook (there's a mix of [`files: \.go$`](https://github.com/dnephin/pre-commit-golang/blob/fd0556d9a362a9a184327a4e8cf3c9f0dea3a47b/.pre-commit-hooks.yaml#L4) and [`types: [go]`](https://github.com/dnephin/pre-commit-golang/blob/fd0556d9a362a9a184327a4e8cf3c9f0dea3a47b/.pre-commit-hooks.yaml#L56))

these get combined together, so your files that will be matched in your repository must match both `^eck-user-mgmt/` **and** end with `.go`

if you run `git ls-files | grep '^eck-user-mgmt' | grep '\.go$'` that should ~roughly replicate what pre-commit does to process file matching

note also that you ran `pre-commit run` -- by default this [**only processes staged files**](https://pre-commit.com/#pre-commit-run).  when adding new hooks [**you probably want to run `pre-commit run --all-files`**](https://pre-commit.com/#4-optional-run-against-all-the-files)

---

disclaimer: I am the author of pre-commit

Comment: Yes but running this command `git ls-files | grep '^eck-user-mgmt' | grep '\.go$'` does discover the `.go` files in my subdir. However `pre-commit run --all-files` still tries to execute from the parent (repo root) folder

Comment: that's an issue of the underlying tool itself then and not the framework (though I suspect that you're trying to make a monorepo setup work, which doesn't gel nicely with git hooks in general -- you may find this relevant: https://stackoverflow.com/q/64773189/812183)

Comment: OK many thanks for the feedback! appreciated